# CMSMS Url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, content-management-system, cmsmadesimple

LE: Figured out that my explaining skills are quite bad so I will make a quick to subject tl;dr at the end.

I recently received a project which implies the customisation of a website build on CMSMS (CMS Made Simple). The website version is **1.11.2** and I am using Apache and mod_rewrite in order to deal with the url rewrite.
I've been trying to solve one small thing related to URL Rewrite but I simply cannot get past it.

The website has installed a module for blog, CGBlog. 
In order to display the content of the blog, I need a page (and a template for the page but we will keep the template out of the discussion because it was no deal in the issue) where to spill all the posts. Basically, a general category/archive page.
Thus I created a page called 'Blog' with the URL 'blog'.
So far, not taking the blog into account, we would have something like example.com/blog.

The blog has an option to add a prefix before every post. So I can make something like example.com/any_prefix_here/title-of-post. Also when inside a blog post it will not keep account for how the archive/category page is called. **So I ve been using this prefix option to make the url look the same. Ex: example.com/blog and when inside an article example.com/blog(added as a prefix)/title-of-the-post**.

Now, the problem is if I try to keep the name of the page of the blog called 'blog' I cannot access it as example.com/blog or I will get 403 forbidden. If I acces it via example.com/anything/blog it will work. If I name the page blog2 then I can access it as example.com/blog2. I can't figure out what's the deal with 'blog', as the word. Also I cannot figure out how to bypass the 403 forbidden.

I even tried to rewrite it somehow via .htaccess but without success.

This is my htaccess at the moment.

```
    # Attempt to override some php settings, these settings may be helpful on some hosts if your
# default configuration does not meet CMS's minimum requirements, and your host
# has given your account appropriate permissions
#php_value upload_max_filesize "10M"
#php_value session_save_path "tmp/cache"

#php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
#php_flag register_globals Off
#php_flag session.use_trans_sid Off

# (this is important, so uncomment if your host permit)
Options -Indexes
ServerSignature Off

Options +FollowSymLinks

# To prevent E_STRICT problems with PHP 5.3+ you can uncomment the following lines
# Note: These settings should only be enabled for production sites!
#php_flag display_startup_errors 0
#php_flag display_errors 0
#php_flag html_errors 0
#php_value docref_root 0
#php_value docref_ext 0

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirects /index.php?page=asfd to /asdf
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# redirects /index.php/asfd to /asdf
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/([^?\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^connsys.ro
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.connsys.ro/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_header.c>
# Disable ETags
Header unset ETag
FileEtag None
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Compress css, plaintext, xml, gif, and images in transport.
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/plain text/xml image/gif image/jpeg image/png
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
# Set expires tags on various files... so that the browser wont attempt to reload them.
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
<IfModule mod_header.c>
  # Setting cache control to public allowes proxy servers to cache the items too.
  Header set Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|woff)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Tl;dr: url rewrite problem/permission problem to the blog page. Page is called 'Blog' and slug/url is 'blog'. I cannot access blog as example.com/blog as I get 403 forbidden. If I access the blog as example.com/anything/blog it works. If I rename the page to blog2 it works as example.com/blog2.

How should I approach this issue? I'd be grateful if you would not downvote and tell me what I did wrong in case I explained something wrong.

Thank you

Comment: The URLs you're talking about are the ones you see in your browser's address bar. You have to find out exactly what they are, internally and what's actually sending the 403. At the top of `index.php`, above all other code, add this line: `var_dump($_SERVER); die;` and record the output of the URLs. If they're all getting through, and there's no significant difference between them (aside from the path part of the URL) then your problem is unlikely to be in your `.htaccess`.

Comment: Well, if I access the homepage I get the var_dump. If I access the /blog I still get the 403 forbidden message from the server. But I doubt it is a server issue as the website as been moved around 3 or 4 web servers, on all experiencing the same issue.

Comment: That's useful; now you know the index.php file is never getting the request. If all servers have the same issue then it's probably your code. Get some rewrite tracing happening to see what's really going on.

Comment: I will look over 'rewrite tracing' as I never actually did something like that. Regarding the rewrite and htaccess, if I empty the htaccess file I still get the 403 forbidden so.. can't we exclude the htaccess?

Comment: Is there a real directory called `blog`? With either no index file/auto-indexing disabled, or with incorrect permissions?

Comment: Walf, you saved my life. It did not crossed my mind for a single second that it may be a folder called blog and that the website was actually trying to read it. To folder was empty, but I simply renamed it and now everything works as intended. I was looking into things way more complex than this. Wow. Thank you a lot! Please submit the comment as an answer so I can mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a real directory called `blog`? With either no index file/auto-indexing disabled, or with incorrect permissions?